# Changing status on entry doesn't save

Tags: add-on, ee3, structure, zoo-visitor

We have an EE site running Visitor and Structure for our intra-net.  When we try and "archive" a member  by setting the status to "closed" or anything else for that matter, the status will not save and just reverts back to it's previous setting.  Any thoughts on where to start debugging this issue?

- EE 3.5.15
- Wiki 3.0.2
- Structure 4.3.8
- Visitor 3.0.1
- Forms 4.0.0
- Low Events 2.0.1
- Polls 2.0
- SEO Lite 1.5.4
- Wygwam 4.1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/14366

I have updated my settings to "Show membergroup in channel entry status" to "no" and the initial finding is that I can now save entry statuses in my test site.  I still need to test that nothing else is affected in my live site but I'm hopeful. :)